# ¿Cómo reemplazar NA con el promedio de los 3 numeros previos?

Tags: r

Yo tengo el siguiente data.frame

```
tmp <- zoo(c(NA,NA,3,5,6,8, NA, NA))
```

Y, necesito reemplazar estos `NA` con el promedio de los 3 datos anteriores. He intentado hacerlo con la funcion `rollapplyr` y, no ha sido posible hacerlo.

Necesito entonces que mi data.frame final sea:

```
(4.222222,4.666667,3,5,6,8,6.333333, 6.777778)
```

Comment: Bienvenido, por favor lee [ask], de paso traduce tu pregunta pues estás en SO en español y agrega mas detalles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No conozco las rutinas `roll*` del paquete `zoo`, seguramente hay alguna manera de resolverlo con ellas, pero de cualquier forma, tampoco es demasiado complejo hacer una función de imputación de `NA` tal como estás buscando:

```
impute_na_with_mean <- function(x, width, reverse=FALSE) {

    if (reverse) {x <- rev(x)}
    start <- head(which(!is.na(x)),1)
    for (i in (start+width):length(x)) {
        x[i] <- ifelse(is.na(x[i]), 
                       mean(x[(i-width):(i-1)], rm.na=TRUE), 
                       x[i])
    }
    if (reverse) {x <- rev(x)}
    x
}

tmp <- c(NA, NA, 3,5,6,8, NA, NA)
tmp <- impute_na_with_mean(tmp,3)
tmp <- impute_na_with_mean(tmp,3, reverse = TRUE)
tmp

[1] 4.222222 4.666667 3.000000 5.000000 6.000000 8.000000 6.333333 6.777778
```

`impute_na_with_mean` empieza a iterar a partir del primer valor no `NA` hacia la derecha, cuando encuentra un `NA` lo reemplaza por la media de los últimos `width` valores. Con `reverse = TRUE` se hace lo mismo pero en la dirección inversa.

Comment: Hola Patricio me ha sido muy util la funcion que has generado. Pero, ahora me encontre con otro error debo aplicar este promedio por un id que es unico.  ¿Cómo podria generarlo asi?

Comment: Agrupando por `ìd` no debería ser muy complejo. Te sugiero que formules una nueva pregunta que con gusto la miramos. Saludos