# ¿Cómo reemplazar NA con el promedio de los 3 numeros previos agrupando por id?

Tags: r

Tengo el siguiente data.frame

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y, necesito generar el promedio para los NA en el campo value de los ultimos 3 datos, pero, esta funcion debe ser por fecha, cod_is y metrica. Es decir, el data.frame debe quedar así: 
[image: iel data.frame debe quedar así:]

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar, armemos tu ejemplo de datos:

```
df <- read.table(text="fecha cod_id metrica value 
2017-03 N1044358 uso NA 
2017-04 N1044358 uso NA 
2017-05 N1044358 uso NA 
2017-06 N1044358 uso 0.5 
2017-07 N1044358 uso 1.6 
2017-08 N1044358 uso 0.9 
2017-09 N1044358 uso 0.7 
2017-10 N1044358 uso 1.0 
2017-03 N1044358 venta NA 
2017-04 N1044358 venta NA 
2017-05 N1044358 venta NA 
2017-06 N1044358 venta 0.2 
2017-07 N1044358 venta 0.8 
2017-08 N1044358 venta 0.4", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactor=FALSE)
```

En segundo lugar, como entiendo que lo que buscas es imputar los `NA` de la forma en que has definido en esta pregunta: [¿Cómo reemplazar NA con el promedio de los 3 números previos?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/256350/c%C3%B3mo-reemplazar-na-con-el-promedio-de-los-3-numeros-previos), voy a ajustar un poco la función de imputación, resultado que ha cambiado el escenario de la pregunta, vamos a mejorarla un poco para que impute de izquierda a derecha y luego al revés:

```
impute_na_with_mean <- function(x, width=3) {

    impute <- function(x, width) {
        start <- head(which(!is.na(x)),1) + width
        if (start < length(x) && length(start) != 0) {
            for (i in start:length(x)) {
                x[i] <- ifelse(is.na(x[i]), 
                               mean(x[(i-width):(i-1)], rm.na=TRUE), 
                               x[i])
            }
        }
        x
    }
    rev(impute(rev(impute(x, width)), width))
}
```

La solución más cómoda es usar `dplyr` para aplicar `impute_na_with_mean` sobre cada grupo de datos:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
    group_by(cod_id, metrica) %>% 
    mutate(value=impute_na_with_mean(value, 3)) %>% 
    ungroup()

# A tibble: 14 x 4
   fecha   cod_id   metrica value
   <chr>   <chr>    <chr>   <dbl>
 1 2017-03 N1044358 uso     0.844
 2 2017-04 N1044358 uso     1.03 
 3 2017-05 N1044358 uso     1    
 4 2017-06 N1044358 uso     0.5  
 5 2017-07 N1044358 uso     1.6  
 6 2017-08 N1044358 uso     0.9  
 7 2017-09 N1044358 uso     0.7  
 8 2017-10 N1044358 uso     1    
 9 2017-03 N1044358 venta   0.385
10 2017-04 N1044358 venta   0.489
11 2017-05 N1044358 venta   0.467
12 2017-06 N1044358 venta   0.2  
13 2017-07 N1044358 venta   0.8  
14 2017-08 N1044358 venta   0.4
```

Nota: al visualizar un `tibble` como el que retorna el código anterior, se muestran menos decimales, pero internamente el dato tiene la precisión apropiada, tal como podrías verificar mediante:

```
df %>% 
    group_by(cod_id, metrica) %>% 
    mutate(value=impute_na_with_mean(value, 3)) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    print.data.frame()
```

Comment: Si bien la funcion itera sobre el cod_id, no lo hace sobre la metrica y al cambiar de metrica no cambia el calculo del promedio. De manera que, sigue calculando el promedio con los datos que traia de atras.

Comment: @SantiagoVásquezRodríguez, no verifico el problema. En mi caso el resultado es el mismo que el que esperas. Por lo que dices el tema es el `group_by` y no la función, estás agrupando por las dos columnas: `group_by(cod_id, metrica)`?

Comment: Patricio, si aplico la función de "group_by" para las columnas indicadas (cod_is, metrica), pero, el calculo lo hace con los valores de la metrica anterior asi:                                                                           6  2017-08 N1044358     uso 0.9000000
7  2017-09 N1044358     uso 0.7000000
8  2017-10 N1044358     uso 1.0000000
9  2017-03 N1044358   venta 0.8666667
10 2017-04 N1044358   venta 0.8555556
11 2017-05 N1044358   venta 0.9074074

Comment: Patricio, será que si creo una llave unica, entre metrica y cod_is, la cual sea una concatenación de estas dos, podrá la función hacer el procedimiento adecuado. Creo que es algo de identificacion de las llaves en el  `group_by(cod_is, metrica)`

Comment: @SantiagoVásquezRodríguez, una aclaración, en tu pregunta, la variable se llama `cod_id` pero en los comentarios mencionas `cod_is`, puede ser eso?

Comment: Que pena Patricio, me equivoque al copiar el nombre, pero, si, el nombre de la variable es `cod_id`. Inclusive intenté con lo anterior, tratando de generar una llave unica, pero aun persiste el error

Comment: @SantiagoVásquezRodríguez, si estás haciendo `group_by(cod_is, metrica)` no veo por que funciona mal. Te repito que no parece un problema de la función sino del agrupamiento, lo cual es raro, prueba con otra función de agregación como `mutate(value=sum(value, na.rm = TRUE))`, la cual debería darte la suma de cada grupo en todas las filas de estos. Si puedes acceder prueba esto https://rstudio.cloud/project/323317

Comment: Patricio, no se si quizas sea que se deba agregar cómo un argumento de la función `impute <- function(x, width)` la de poder aplicar la función por grupos. Es decir, quizas sea la falta de un argumento en la función `impute <- function(x, width)`, puesto que al aplicarla en el `group_by` , no reconoce el argumento par agrupar para estas variables `(cod_id, metrica)`

Comment: No, `impute_na_with_mean` solo necesita trabajar con un vector de entrada, quién "decide" como es ese vector, es el `group_by()`. Validemos en primer lugar que sea esto: https://rstudio.cloud/project/323317 lo que estás esperando como solución, luego si el problema lo tienes con otro conjunto de datos, te pido que compartas un ejemplo de estos antes y después procesarlos.

Comment: Patricio, raramente cuando genero mi codigo en el enlace [https://rstudio.cloud/project/323467] el codigo corre bien y, la función hace su trabajo como debe, pero, en mi maquina no.No sé si quizas sea la version de R studio, actualmente me encuentro sobre la versión 3.5.3, no se si pueda ser esto que me este afectando. Intentaré cambiarle el kernel a R y trabajar sobre la versión  `3.5.2`

Comment: Patricio, que pasa con la función cuando en la variable a imputar tiene todos sus columnas en `NA`, es decir, si la longuitud de la variable a imputar es 43 y todo este array es `NA`, ¿ahi la funcion encontraría alguna dificultad?. Saludos

Comment: como en este caso [https://rstudio.cloud/project/324655]

Comment: No contemplé que se reciba un vector completo de `NA`, ya modifique esto en la función y en la respuesta, de cualquier forma te retornará los mismos `NA` del vector. En cuanto al proyecto que compartes, no lo puedo abrir, revisa que la configuración de acceso, quien puede ver el proyecto tiene que estar configurado en "everyone"

Comment: Patricio, en verdad aprecio bastante tu colabroración. En serio que ha sido genuina, me acabas de sacar un atolladero del que no encontraba salida. Muchas gracias. Eres muy amable y servicial.

Comment: `impute_na_with_mean <- function(x, width=3) {

    impute <- function(x, width) {
        start <- head(which(!is.na(x)),1) + width
        if (start < length(x) && length(start) != 0) {
            for (i in start:length(x)) {
                x[i] <- ifelse(is.na(x[i]), 
                               mean(x[(i-width):(i-1)], rm.na=TRUE), 
                               x[i])
            }
        }
        x
    }
    rev(impute(rev(impute(x, width)), width))
}`  Nice. Perfecto. Justo lo que necesitaba